# How to package & share Selenium scripts with non-technical team?

Tags: windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, dependencies, environment

I have a few python/selenium scripts that automate tedious work in browser-based apps (e.g., data entry from a CSV file).

I would like to share the scripts with my team members who are tech-savvy but don't know how to code.

**How can I package up the scripts with all the dependencies so that "it just works" when downloaded?**

Dependencies are:

- Install python and add to PATH
- Install selenium, pandas, autopylogger
- Install selenium chromedrivers

...and a few other simple changes to variables/file paths in the scripts

My first instinct was to dockerize the environment, but because the automation need to use the user's Chrome profiles and docker runs on WSL I imagine that would cause issues. And setting up WSL + Docker Desktop isn't exactly simplifying things.

Jenkins, Replit, Maven, and other hosted options would have a similar issue using the user's Chrome profile (I think?)

I'm currently thinking I'll write a .BAT script that sets up the environment, but I haven't done that before and am hoping there's an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say,

1)Create a Jenkin job.
In Selenium, you can pass chrome user profile as an argument. They can save their chrome user profile from the chrome browser and pass it as an argument through jenkins.
Below is the sample code of how to pass custom chrome profiles:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data- 
dir=C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 2")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', 
chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")
```

Let them store their profile in a accessible path, where it can be passed as an argument to Jenkins